# Can I collect product data with a community extension

Tags: product, api, data

I am developing a community extension in which the client would like to gather and collect the store's product data.

To be specific, the extension is for a service the user is paying for. The extension allows them to connect to the service with their Magento site easier. The developer of the extension would like to collect the store's product data and retrieve it, sending it back to their servers to improve the Magento user's service.

My question is whether or not there are any restrictions on this behavior from an extension? Should the user simply be prompted to agree to share the data? There is no customer data involved, only products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no restriction. If the extension isn't self hosted, you can use Magento's API to retrieve information about a product, or a list of products:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.info.html

You will just need to create the relevant user/permissions

[image]

Comment: This would require the user to enable and configure their api though, right?

Comment: That's correct. They will have to create a role, and create a user for that role. (see visual above)

Comment: If I were to programmatically create a role, user and enable the api, would **that** be frowned upon or disallowed to your knowledge? Thanks for the info.

Comment: As long as you make the customer agree to it, I don't see it being a problem (not programmatically  at least)

Comment: I ended up programmatically creating a new api role and user with my module's data-install script. Works like a charm.